# Develop custom Javascript html editor

Tags: javascript

I want to develop a custom javascript html editor. My starting point was: 
http://hypertextarea.sourceforge.net/

I understood how the mechanism works but the problem is that I cannot find the point where if I focus the iframe I have the cursor displayed.

Then if I press a key I see the letter entered there. Can you please explain me how this javascript shows the editor cursor and how it write in the iframe the characters that I write?

All javascript used by this editor is at 
http://hypertextarea.sourceforge.net/javascript/HyperTextArea.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is handled by the function `enableDesignMode` (line 755), which tries to turn on [`designMode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla) for the `<iframe>`.

In other words, this is a browser feature and you can make an HTML page editable with nothing more than a single line of JS (or a single HTML attribute), but the library provides other niceties like the ability to format text and insert tables.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you want: onKeyPress and onFocus

Comment: this editor generates me an iframe that has no function attached to this events. That's why I have no idee how it works.

Comment: This isn't what you asked for. You said "Can you please give me the javascript function that runs when I press a key or when I focus the iframe?" Create a standard input field, you'll note that it too has a cursor which blinks.